# Does SO allow multiple accounts with the same username?

Tags: discussion

I have two accounts.

My first Account was created through Stack Exchange and was used to ask questions. But since it is question-banned, I created a second account through Facebook to answer questions.

If a username already exists, I cannot create an account through Stack Exchange. But if I create an account through Facebook, it would be accepted even though there exists an account with the same username created through Stack Exchange. Is this a bug, or does Stack Overflow  accept multiple accounts with the same username?

If Stack Overflow allows this, my question is:

Suppose I search my username on this site, which account would be shown in the results?

Comment: You shouldn't make a second account to bypass a question ban. You should go through the [proper process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/201262) to get that account unbanned.

Comment: Can you please rewrite this in English? I understand it's not your native language, but same for me.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I tried, but the second two paragraphs have completely got me beat.

Comment: See now ! sorry

Comment: After reading five times I have no slight clue what you are asking here.

Comment: Why create another account just to answer questions? You can still *answer* questions if you're banned from *asking* new ones.

Comment: "I have two accounts. My first account I used to ask questions, and it was question banned..." It's nice that you turn yourself in, now fasten your seatbelt and watch all of your accounts being merged.

Comment: @Ramesh you didn't change anything, still no clue what is your point here.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I think this one is confused on how it is possible to have users with identical usernames...not aware that the unique constraint is the id, not the name.

Comment: My point is  i have two  same username in this site . this time Suppose i search my username in this site ,Which username details give this site?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby maybe, maybe not. Really can't know.

Comment: Hey Why All of you put down vote . It's my question  is i have two same username in this site . this time Suppose i search my username in this site ,Which username details give this site? . Thats all .it's any wrong question ???

Comment: @RameshRajendran each user has unique numeric ID. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2291535/ramesh-rajendran) has ID of 2291535 and [that other account with same display name](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2218635/ramesh-rajendran) has ID of 2218635. What about it?

Comment: I don't care for my account will be ban.But i want to know is this bug ?

Comment: You get downvotes because you created another account after getting post banned and people don't like such behavior.

Comment: It's not a bug. You have two accounts. Two Different accounts that have the same name but different IDs.

Comment: So what ? My old account was ban in ask question feature . So i create new account . It's fun ya ! So how can i ask question for this site ?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Not to mention that the question fits the downvote-tooltip (unclear or not useful).

Comment: @tombull89 You are  correct . I want this answer only...

Comment: Post ban is per site. You can ask here on Meta even if you are question banned on Stack Overflow. If cheating is considered fun by you then well, you deserve all the downvotes and much more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have done exactly the wrong thing by creating a second account to answer questions.

One of the ways you can help lift a question ban is by providing good quality answers, so you should have just used the first account.

Comment: But I don't know  for how to release the question ban.So, i created new account . Sorry

Comment: Read the link at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers?lq=1.

Comment: @RameshRajendran You received a message with a link to the following post which explains what you need to do to get unbanned: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998

Answer (score 9):

It's not a bug. You have two accounts. Two different accounts that have the same name but different IDs. This is how one is banned and the other is now.

`So i create new account . It's fun ya !`

Do not do this. Your accounts will be merged.

Comment: oh !! lol ; Sorry i am a freshers in  this site !!